# How to change graphical parameters of ordiellipse plot? Ordiellipse plot cuts off data

Tags: r, plot, vegan

[Ordiellipse plot, part of ellipses are shown in bottom left corner, no other information is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIVtX.jpg)

I am trying to create an NMDS plot with bee species data grouped by the presence/absence of mines. In the following line of code beematrix=species abundances by site and beesmine= defines which sites contain mined areas.

```
beematrix=read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1)
beesmine=read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1)
beesmatrix=as.matrix(beematrix)
beematrix=t(beesmatrix)
library(vegan)
rankindex(beematrix, beematrix)
bees.nmds=metaMDS(beematrix, distance = "kulczynski")
for (i in 1:5) print (metaMDS(beesmatrix, distance = "kulczynski", k=i, trace = FALSE)$stress*100)
bees.nmds=metaMDS(beesmatrix, distance = "kulczynski", k=3)
plot(bees.nmds)
plot.new()
ordiellipse(bees.nmds, groups=beesmine$Mine,label = TRUE)
##ordiellipse is smushed into corner of screen and is impossible to read
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use `plot.new`: it destroys the previous plot and faults `ordiellipse`.  Function `ordiellipse` will **add** ellipses to an **existing** ordination plot, but you have no existing plot after you used `plot.new()` which destroys all that exist.

What led you to use `plot.new()`?

Comment: I had an error message earlier that asked me to call plot.new(). I just tried running it again without it and it works great. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you must first `plot` the ordination result (as `plot(bees.nmds)`), and then you can add ellipses with `ordiellipse()`. If you have not plotted the ordination result, you get an error message that you must plot it first, and this message asks you to "call plot.new" (*i.e.*, to use `plot(bees.nmds)`).